# Triangle apparently has two equivalent angles, but not really

Tags: triangles, angle

What angles are ${a, b, c, d}$? As far as I know, $a = 180^\circ - 130^\circ = 50^\circ$, however, I expected $c$ to be the same as $a$ and it's not, according to cimt.org.uk.

(Figure from [cimt.org.uk](https://www.cimt.org.uk/projects/mepres/book7/bk7i5/bk7_5i6.htm))

[image: Figure]

Comment: It's an isosceles triangle. What do you know about isosceles triangles?

Comment: @CameronWilliams They've two equal lengths and two equal angles anywhere?

Comment: If $a$ is the angle between two equal long sides , then $b=c$. But that is not given as formulated.

Comment: The equal angles are the angles opposing the equal-lenght sides.

Comment: You should draw an isosceles triangle and measure the angles. This is a fairly basic fact and indicates a major gap in your knowledge.

Comment: The hash marks indicate the drawing is deceptive - the two sides that are equal meet at angle $a,$ not $b.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks. It's a dumb question, but this drawing isn't very clear to me

Comment: @CameronWilliams That seems harsh. This is a standard diagram, yes, but it is standard because the image gives the impression that two different angles are equal. And only the hash marks on the line segment indicate that it is another pair.

Comment: @Hydroper It is important to get used to the fact that drawings in geometry are not meant to be accurate, and you are expected to instead interpret the meaning. Here, the hash marks in the segments indicate which two sides are equal, in spite of the drawing.

Answer (score 1):

the sides marked with two stripes are equal, which makes the other one the base. Angles adjacent to the base are equal. So b and c are equal. As $a = 50$, and the sum of the angles of a triangle is 180, that makes angles $ b = c = (180 - 50):2 = 65 $ so the angle $ d = 180 - 65 = 115$